# mod rewrite urls for search page parameters

Tags: apache, .htaccess, variables, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting my search page variables with:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /search.php?search=$1&cat=$2 [L]
```

which works if I go to /search/test/Members

However if I am on the home page and use the search box, the URL shows as:

```
/search?search=test&cat=Members
```

How do I rewrite the URL so that when a user uses the search form the URL shows as:

```
/search/test/Members
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these rules:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+search\.php\?search=([^&]+)&cat=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /search/%1/%2? [L,R]
```

in order to redirect the browser to a new URL. The cleaner URL will then be requested and the rule you already have will internally rewrite it *back* to what it's supposed to be.